# How can i stop auto-shutdown in nitrous.io

Tags: bash, nitrousio

How can i stop the auto-shutdown in nitrous.io . I don't want to shut it down and i am using free account !

I am using phantomjs though but it shuts itself down after 12 min

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I binded the server port with 0.0.0.0 and now it's running without any shutdown !